# incompatible pointer type conversion warning in C socket programming

Tags: c, pointers

```
list *attachnode(list *tmp,list *hd)//function to get the ip address
{
   if(hd==NULL)       
   {
            hd=tmp;
   }
   else
   {
            tmp->next=hd;               
            hd=tmp;
   }
   return(hd);
}
```

tmp->next=hd giving a warning of incompatible type pointer conversion by default 
"next" is list type.

Comment: the function above is to send the ip address...

Comment: How is list declared?

Comment: What about a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you say, "next" is "list type" but i believe it should be "list *" type

but without your typedef we cannot be sure

okay, your comment, my edith:

it should be `typedef struct list {...; struct list *next;} list;`

the reason is, that C does need a forward declaration, else it could not determine the "type" of next. visualication: `typedef struct {xxx *next;} yyy;`

Comment: it is actually list * type in typedef structure

Comment: typedef struct
{
 char *ip;
 char *port;
 int  dis;
 struct list *next;
}list;